# Are remote addresses pushed in Git?

Tags: git, git-remote

When I'm working on a Git project, I clone the repo from Github, then add a remote: `git remote add bitbucket https://foo@bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git` then I commit and push to both `origin` and `bitbucket`. Is the new remote also saved in Github? Will the other users see that I have added a new remote? Or is it just stored locally?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which remotes are used for your copy of a repository is not part of the repository itself and thus not pushed.
Note that the remotes can also be local or on private networks.

Comment: Thanks! But I have a follow-up questions. If remotes are not pushed, how do I see two different remotes when I clone the repo from Github? When I try to add the third one, it does not get published, as you suggested, but how is the second one saved there?

Comment: When you clone from GitHub you initially only have one remote (maybe listed for both push and pull). You can add more locally, but GitHub won't know about those.  You can also configure "git push" to push to all remotes, if that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, I have 4 remotes listed in total (push & fetch for 2 URLs). I didn't change any configuration. So I guess I added the second one locally too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not. The git remotes are not a part of the git repository, and are only stored locally inside the `.git` folder.

Answer (score 3):

No, the remotes settings are locally inside your .git folder and are not pushed back to any of the remotes you've set